# Playing YouTube Videos in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Recently I started developing an app which contains the provision to play the youtube videos. Initially I thought it may be an easier task, and later I realized that it is not going to be an easy one. My all other works related to that apps are over and the only pending work is youtube integration. Can any one please help me to complete this. Or send me some useful links that help me for integrating with youtube.

Answer (score 1):

These previous answers may help you:

- [YouTube on Windows Phone with MediaElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272293/youtube-on-windows-phone-with-mediaelement)
- [How to launch a YouTube URL on Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170587/how-to-launch-a-youtube-url-on-windows-phone-7)

Basically, it looks like currently you can't embed videos within your app, but you can (with some url kludging) launch the external viewer as long as the user has installed the youTube app.