# Play any kind of videos in windows phone 8 like (youtub,brightcove,dvidshub)

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Can Any one help me am new in windows phone.

**Play any kind of videos in windows phone 8 like (youtub,brightcove,dvidshub)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the `Youtube` class to play the youtube videos from `Codeplex`. Have a look into [this](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube&referringTitle=Documentation)

Reference:
[How to Play youtube videos in windows phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778699/)

http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2013/07/embed-youtube-videos-into-your-windows.html

If you want to play a normal video from your local files you could use the `MediaElement`. This [sample](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Video_Playback_with_MediaElement_in_Windows_Phone) could be helpful.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

you can have Reference form **Nokia Developer** Article given here ([Video Playback with MediaElement in Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Video_Playback_with_MediaElement_in_Windows_Phone)).

-This article demonstrates how to play a video using the [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) Windows Phone control and also how to play video from remote server in the default media player using [MediaPlayerLauncher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.mediaplayerlauncher%28VS.92%29.aspx).